# custom logging does not works when set in systemProperties

Tags: corda

I want to change log configuration for a node for that I have written a custom xml file where I have changed some configuration related to some specific module and rolling policies and I am using command: `java -Dlog4j.configurationFile=custom-log.xml -jar corda.jar`

This works fine with my custom configuration, but when I set same configuration in systemProperties section of `node.conf` as:

```
systemProperties = { 
    -Dlog4j.configurationFile = custom-log.xml
}
```

It does not follow my custom logging configuration. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

`systemProperties = { 
    -Dlog4j.configurationFile = custom-log.xml
}`

pass it as this:

`systemProperties = { 
    log4j.configurationFile = custom-log.xml
}`

-D is automatically appended